# The closure of $(a,b)$ with respect to the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

> If $T$ is the discrete topology on the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$, find the closure of $(a,b)$.

Is it $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$? I just began to learn topology, and feel a little confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the discrete topology, every subset is open. Therefore the complement of $(a,b)$ is open and hence $(a,b)$ is closed and thus its own closure.

Comment: Oh,right, so the closure of (a,b) is still (a,b)! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.